The DOS program seemingly ignores the 'print *' instruction?
This simple program (16-bit assembly using debug on FreeDOS, code below) expects a one-digit integer. It stops if the integer is either 0 or >1. If it's 1, it generates a new line, prints '*', then generates another new line, and stops. The code, however, doesn't do what is expected. In particular, it doesn't print the '*'. I asked ChatGPT, but it didn't find any obvious error.
The source file (prinst.txt) contains this:
a 100
mov ah,02  ; prepare for print
mov dl,3f  ; set '?'
int 21     ; print '?'
mov dl,20  ; set ' '
int 21     ; print ' ', hence generate the '?(space)' prompt.
mov ah,01  ; prepare for saving user input
int 21     ; ask user input. The input saved in al.
mov ah,02  ; prepare for print
mov dl,0d  ; set LF
int 21     ; print LF
mov dl,0a  ; set CR
int 21     ; print CR, hence generate new line
cmp al,30  ; compare user input in al, with '0'
je 012e    ; if equal jump to address 0126 (e.g. int 20)
cmp al,31  ; compare input with '1'
jne 012e   ; if input != '1', jump to address 0126
mov ah,02  ; prepare for print
mov dl,2a  ; set the symbol to print, e.g. '*'
int 21     ; print '*'
mov dl,0d  ; set LF
int 21     ; print LF
mov dl,0a  ; set CR
int 21     ; print CR, hence generate new line
int 20

n prinst.com
rcx
30
w
q

Assembled in FreeDOS using debug
C:\>debug <prinst.txt> prinst.lst

The listing file (prinst.lst) contains this
-a 100
0DAB:0100 mov ah,02  ; prepare for print
0DAB:0102 mov dl,3f  ; set '?'
0DAB:0104 int 21     ; print '?'
0DAB:0106 mov dl,20  ; set ' '
0DAB:0108 int 21     ; print ' ', hence generate the '?(space)' prompt.
0DAB:010A mov ah,01  ; prepare for saving user input
0DAB:010C int 21     ; ask user input. The input saved in al.
0DAB:010E mov ah,02  ; prepare for print
0DAB:0110 mov dl,0d  ; set LF
0DAB:0112 int 21     ; print LF
0DAB:0114 mov dl,0a  ; set CR
0DAB:0116 int 21     ; print CR, hence generate new line
0DAB:0118 cmp al,30  ; compare user input in al, with '0'
0DAB:011A je 012e    ; if equal jump to address 012e (e.g. int 20)
0DAB:011C cmp al,31  ; compare input with '1'
0DAB:011E jne 012e   ; if input != '1', jump to address 012e
0DAB:0120 mov ah,02  ; prepare for print
0DAB:0122 mov dl,2a  ; set the symbol to print, e.g. '*'
0DAB:0124 int 21     ; print '*'
0DAB:0126 mov dl,0d  ; set LF
0DAB:0128 int 21     ; print LF
0DAB:012A mov dl,0a  ; set CR
0DAB:012C int 21     ; print CR, hence generate new line
0DAB:012E int 20
0DAB:0130 
-n prinst.com
-rcx
CX 0000  :30
-w
Writing 0030 bytes
-q

And the output
C:\>prinst.com
? 0

C:\>prinst.com
? 1

Thus, the instruction to print '*' is kind of ignored. Maybe the conditional jumps are not working as expected? Something else?
I tried FreeDOS's debugger (installed on a virtual machine) and DOSBox-x's debugger (version 2024.07.01) on a MacOS` and got the same results.
Also, I know the DOS debugger is terrible, explicitly addressing is not recommended, etc., and I must use a better assembler, s.t. TASM/MASM/NASM.

Apparently int 21/02 destroys al. dosbox source says: "Not in the official specs, but happens nonetheless. (last written character)" To fix, for example add a push ax/pop ax pair around your prints before processing the input.

Re: the last paragraph: NASM etc. are just assemblers.  They just turn source text into binary machine code (optionally in a .obj file, or a flat binary which works as a .com executable).  You'd want a separate debugger, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86-16/info -  lDebug is free and I think is good.  Copies of TurboDebugger are also available I think, along with TASM.  But I'd recommend NASM and lDebug.

Maybe the conditional jumps are not working as expected? Something else? - You're using a debugger; the whole point of a debugger is to be able to single-step your code to see the path of execution, and check register values as you step.

@Jaster, you are right; the push ax/pop ax did indeed fix the issue! Thank you.

@PeterCordes, I think your suggestion makes sense. Though, as a newbie, I find NASM and IDebug a bit frightening at the moment :-)

I wouldn't recommend DOS / x86-16 as the first assembly language you learn.  32 or 64-bit x86 under a modern OS are simpler (no segmentation, and the system calls are the same ones you can use from C programs).  And you can use GUI debuggers under your native desktop OS.  (Or if using an AArch64 system like a mac, that's also a great ISA to learn.)  Learning the extra complexities of the limitations imposed by 16-bit x86 (like only a few register combinations in addressing modes, and segment registers) is something you can learn later.

@PeterCordes, thank you again for your study tips. I checked the NASM assembler, but it seems the issue persists. Here is the code in .asm format (I asked ChatGPT to do the conversion as I don't know the NASM syntax, hopefully is correct): https://mia.nl.tab.digital/s/mrkZ2TztK24kGK9. Running nasm -f bin prinst.asm -o prinst.com and executing prinst.com from dosbox-x gives the same output as in the post. Thus, it seems that pop/push protection is also necessary here.

Yeah, of course, the same machine instructions do the same thing no matter what assembler you use to create your .com.  Using better tools including a debugger just makes it easier to debug and change your code.  You could also disassemble your .com into NASM syntax with ndisasm, or Agner Fog's objconv disassembler (https://www.agner.org/optimize/) whose output is valid NASM syntax (or MASM or GAS if you use that option instead).

@utobi "I think your suggestion makes sense. Though, as a newbie, I find NASM and IDebug a bit frightening at the moment :-)" lDebug maintainer here. You can use lDebug in the same way as MS-DOS Debug or FreeDOS Debug/X. (lDebug is a fork of FreeDOS Debug/X.) Your script would work exactly the same in lDebug. It just adds new commands, an expression evaluator, Extensions for lDebug, etc.

@ecm that's encouraging :-).  I'll try it out!
